# List converts class to parent

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    virtual void doSomething() const;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
    void doSomething() const;
};
```

Then I have function:

```
void putToList(const A &a)
{
   a.doSomething(); // this one depends on what was set as argument A or B class (putToList(A()) or putToList(B()))
   std::list<A> As;
   As.push_back(a);
   As.back().doSomething(); //this always calls doSomething from A
}
```

My question is that whyafter taking from list, the object is A and how to prevent it change type and make it B if object I passed to function was of class B.

Comment: yawn yawn yawn slicing

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, too bad I have but one up-vote to give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `As` is `std::list<A>`. It stores `A` objects. If you try to put a `B` object in, it will be *sliced* and you'll get only the `A` part of it. Whenever you take an element from the list, it is an `A` object and so any function you call on it will be a member function of `A`.

There are two ways to get polymorphic behaviour in C++: pointers or references. For example, you could store a pointer to `A` in the list:

```
std::list<A*> As;
As.push_back(&a);
As.back()->doSomething();
```

Of course, it is preferred to wrap it up in a smart pointer.

To use references, you could use a `std::list<std::reference_wrapper<A>>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is the nice example of ***object slicing*** problem, where instance of `B` is being sliced to the instance of `A` and thus loses what is specific for `B` (see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1168156)).

You will not achieve run-time polymorphism of this kind while using a list of objects. You could use a list of pointers instead:

```
std::list<A*> As;
As.push_back(new B());
As.back()->doSomething(); // method of B is invoked
```

or yet even better: take advantage of RAII for once again and use smart pointers instead of naked pointers (i.e. `A*` like shown in my example).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Fair enough. I added a note about it :)